# Weird CSS mangling - Unexpected border-bottom value in a:hover

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

SASS inserts unexpected CSS on production server and messes up my **a:hover**

This is fragment of my application.css:

```
pre {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 11px; }

a {
    color: #000000;
}
a:visited {
    color: #666666;
}
a:hover {
    border-bottom: none;
}

div {
  &.field, &.actions {
    margin-bottom: 10px; } }
```

however on production server firefox reports following css:

```
pre {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 10px;
}
a {
    color: #000000;
}
a:visited {
    color: #666666;
}
a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #777777;
}
div.field, div.actions {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

on my development machine firefox shows following CSS:

```
a:hover {
    border-bottom: medium none;
}
```

I use Rails 3.2.13 and I have never seen problem like this. I have wasted whole afternoon trying to find a solution. This problem breaks my home page and makes it look very unprofessional.

Comment: Not an answer, but a quick fix could be to replace `border-bottom: none;` with `border-bottom-width: 0;`

Comment: Sass doesn't randomly insert code *just 'cause*.

Comment: Sadly it's a problem with asset compilation on production server. Now my production server clearly has different CSS than my development machine.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice it before, but the problem was a result of CSS not being refreshed on production server.

Answer (score 5):

First, `border-bottom` is a [shorthand property](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200502/efficient_css_with_shorthand_properties/). It combines `border-bottom-width`, `border-bottom-color` and `border-bottom-style`. The values of those properties can appear in any order. Any of them can be omitted.

`none` is a value from `border-bottom-style`.

Second, what Firefox shows in its inspection feature, is not exaclty your CSS. It shows what it treats the CSS like. `border-bottom: medium none;` means that you changed the style of border to `none`, while the width remains as `medium` (apparently, it was inherited).

To see the actual CSS, open the actual CSS file and look inside. It will also let you view media query wrappers.

Third, to remove bottom border, use `border-bottom: 0;`. That will be treated as `border-bottom-width: 0;`, which effectively removes the border.

Comment: Thank you very much for thorough explanation.

Comment: Hey ruby_object, don't forget to upvote and select the answer!